# Go to top of page on image click

Tags: javascript, html

For some odd reason, none of javascript codes for pushing page to top upon click work for me. So I am posting here, maybe you guys get more luck with this than I do. It throws me to the top, but without smooth transition. It almost look like as if script isn't working...

```
<footer>
    <div id="right"><a href="#" id="TopPage"><img id="arrow" src="Img/arrow.png" alt=""></a></div>  
</footer>

<script>
$('#TopPage').click(function(){
          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
})  
</script>
```

I get the following error in my console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at F0mL36E:95

Comment: It works for me well.

Comment: Does it have smooth transition for you ?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: This one actually:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at F0mL36E:95

Comment: make sure you loaded the jQuery library

Comment: ^^ That's correct above, One way to do this is include `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> ` in the document.

Comment: Googling your error will show you the solution with probable duplicates for this question, to which has been asked many times, seeing the hits on Google leading back to Stack

Comment: That may be true, but even with included script this doesn't work for me

Comment: After you included jQuery do you get any other errors?

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: 404 this time Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Looks like there was a gremlin character in the above -- src is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js so `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` (update -- stack overflow appears to add that gremlin character, so visit the link above and once it loads use that url as the source).

Comment: Now that did the trick ! Thank you!

Comment: You can try https://github.com/scrollpress/scrollpress

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps. Also as @quetzaluz mention above, make sure you add the library to the end of your page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('#TopPage').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 'slow');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that your JQuery library is imported *before* your .js file. I usually end up putting mine in the head of the HTML, and my .js file in the end of the body. Otherwise, the browser loads and processes the .js file before JQuery, which results in errors like that.

Comment: Done that, it runs smoothly now.